# Kobuki "gyro" versus "inertia" packets?

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Kobuki (a.k.a. TurtleBot 2) and I am trying to understand some of the source code in the [kobuki](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki) and [kobuki_core](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_core) packages.  Specifically, the [inertia.hpp](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_core/blob/indigo/kobuki_driver/include/kobuki_driver/packets/inertia.hpp) file refers to both the angle and the angle_rate.  I was wondering how the raw angle is obtained at this low level if only a gyro is used?  Also, there is a separate [three_axis_gyro.hpp](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_core/blob/indigo/kobuki_driver/include/kobuki_driver/packets/three_axis_gyro.hpp) file that seems to be handling the gyro so I'm not sure which data is actually being used to compute the Kobuki's orientation.

Can someone help me find where in the source code the robot's orientation angle (around the z-axis) is actually computed or measured?

Thanks!

patrick

http://www.pirobot.org/wordpress

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230666/kobuki-%22gyro%22-versus-%22inertia%22-packets?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

source code in kobuki.cpp

```
ecl::Angle<double> Kobuki::getHeading() const
{
  ecl::Angle<double> heading;
  // raw data angles are in hundredths of a degree, convert to radians.
  heading = (static_cast<double>(inertia.data.angle) / 100.0) * ecl::pi / 180.0;
  return ecl::wrap_angle(heading - heading_offset);
}

double Kobuki::getAngularVelocity() const
{
  // raw data angles are in hundredths of a degree, convert to radians.
  return (static_cast<double>(inertia.data.angle_rate) / 100.0) * ecl::pi / 180.0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [woshidag](https://answers.ros.org/users/26689/woshidag/) with karma: 16 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0